# Migrating a schema from one database to other

Tags: db2

As part of some requirement, I need to migrate a schema from some existing database to a new schema in a different database. Some part of it is already done and now I need to compare the 2 schema and make changes in the new schema as per gap finding.
I am not using a tool and was trying to understand some details using syscat command but could not get much success.
Any pointer on what is the best way to solve this?

Regards,
Ramakant

Answer (score 1):

A tool really is the best way to solve this – [IBM Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/) is free and can compare schemas between databases.

Assuming you are using DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows, you can do a rudimentary compare by looking at selected columns in `SYSCAT.TABLES` and `SYSCAT.COLUMNS` (for table definitions), and `SYSCAT.INDEXES` (for indexes).  Exporting this data to files and using `diff` may be the easiest method.  However, doing this for more complex structures (tables with range or database partitioning, foreign keys, etc) will become very complex very quickly as this information is spread across a lot of different system catalog tables.

An alternative method would be to extract DDL using the `db2look` utility.  However, you can't specify the order that db2look outputs objects (db2look extracts DDL based on the objects' `CREATE_TIME`), so you can't extract DDL for an entire schema into a file and expect to use `diff` to compare.  You would need to extract DDL into a separate file for each table.

Comment: Well I started using the following commands to start with                  SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.TABLES, SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.VIEWS ,SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.ROUTINES etc.. however I am still trying to understand as to how to query all the packages ,triggers, indexes etc belonging to a schema and compare it with new schema. Will also check the possibility of using IBM data studio

Comment: I wouldn't waste my time trying to do that querying the system catalog directly.  Use a tool or at least `db2look`, with the caveats noted above.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SchemaCrawler for IBM DB2](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/), a free open-source tool that is designed to produce text output that is designed to be diffed. You can get very detailed information about your schema, including view and stored procedure definitions. All of the information that you need will be output in a single file, and can be compared very easily using a standard diff tool.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler

Comment: This is an interesting tool, but it provides only a logical view of the schema – it doesn't include any physical attributes like tablespaces, partitioning keys, identity columns, etc.

Comment: Ian, data such as tablespaces and so on is available, but not in the standard output. You can output it using custom scripts. Or, you can output the results of SYSCAT queries specifically for that additional data.

Comment: Can you provide a script that completely replicates the output of the `db2look` utility that IBM provides to generate DDL, but only in a nice format that can be used with `diff`?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately as per company policy, cannot use these tools at this point of time. So am writing some program using JDBC to get the details and do some comparison kind of stuff.